# How i can fix the increasing order summation code?

Tags: java

I want from the java to reads all numbers from the user as long as the number entered by user is bigger than the previous number. But i could write it for only positive numbers. How i can fix code below if all numbers included. If it is possible please write the solution for beginners because its my first year in computer science in college and I haven't learn a lot yet.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class IncreasingOrder extends ConsoleProgram {

public void run() {

    int previousNumber = 0;

    int total = 0;

    int count = 0;

    while(true) {
        int n = readInt("Enter > ");
        if (n <= previousNumber) break;

        total += n;
        count++;
        previousNumber = n;
    }
    println("You have entered " + count + " numbers in increasing order.");
    println("Sum of these " + count + " numbers is " + total + ".");        
}
```

}

Comment: When dealing with negative numbers, you are comparing at the 1st iteration a negative number with the value `0` of `previousNumber`, which causes the loop to break. You have to initialize `previousNumber` with the minimum value an integer can get, which is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written:

```
int previousNumber = 0;
```

The reason why you cannot input negative numbers is because the program assumes the very first value, not included in the computations, was 0: if you type in anything less the program exits.

There are two ways to solve this problem. You could set a smaller initial value for `previousNumber`, so that some negative numbers are allowed. For example if you set it to -1000 the user could input -999 or anything greater. What value should you use? Well, we know that all int values are greater than or equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` so you could use that.

But then the user happens to input `-2147483648` and it's rejected. Why? Because it happens to be exactly `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. So that's not a good solution.

The first number the user inputs needs special treatment, because it cannot be compared with a previous input. One solution therefore is reading the first number separately, outside of the loop:

```
int previousNumber = readInt("Enter > ");

int total = previousNumber;

int count = 1;

while(true) {
    int n = readInt("Enter > ");
    if (n <= previousNumber) break;

    total += n;
    count++;
    previousNumber = n;
}
```

Another solution is maintaining a flag variable that tells you if the user has already given the first input or not:

```
boolean isFirst = true;
while(true) {
    int n = readInt("Enter > ");
    if (!isFirst && n <= previousNumber) break;

    total += n;
    count++;
    previousNumber = n;
    isFirst = false;
}
```

Which style you should use depends on your tastes.

Answer (score 2):

use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` instead of `0` for `previousNumber` initialization.
Then should work for negative numbers.

Comment: What if Integer.MIN_VALUE entered as the first value. program will exit.

Answer (score 0):

for sure you are not going to break with the first number. so set a boolean to store status. and don't check if that number is bigger until the 2nd number entered. good luck with the ACM.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class IncreasingOrder extends ConsoleProgram {

public void run() {

    int previousNumber = 0;

    int total = 0;

    int count = 0;
    boolean first = true;
    while(true) {
        int n = readInt("Enter > ");
        if (!first && n <= previousNumber) break;
        first = false;
        total += n;
        count++;
        previousNumber = n;
    }
    println("You have entered " + count + " numbers in increasing order.");
    println("Sum of these " + count + " numbers is " + total + ".");        
}
}
```